# index of posted data in node

Tags: html, node.js, express

I have a simple HTML  file like this :

```html
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:3000/post">
   <input name="name" type="text"/><br />
   <input name="last_name" type="text"/><br />
   <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I receive post data with this node (express) code :

```
app.route('/post')
.post(function(req, res, next) {
    res.send(req.body.name);
});
```

for example for this input :

> Richard Stallman

I receive something like this :

> ["Richard","Stallman"]

But I need them like this :

```
{ name : "Richard" ,last_name : "Stallman" }
```

Or something like this.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to approach getting posted data in Express is to use [express body parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser).

This will give you an object with the keys matching your named form fields (as you appear to desire).

You'll probably want the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` parser.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

If you're using `GET` as the method on the form, you can pull the object straight out of express using `req.query` without any extra middleware.

So if the form sends the following request:

`www.mysite.com/input?name=richard&last_name=stallman`

Your `req.query` will be `{name: 'richard', last_name: 'stallman'}`

Comment: There are too many data in each form and that HTML is just a simple example.So I can't do this.

Comment: And HTML with `method="get"` send data with their names ,I think this is able with `post`.

Comment: Updated answer again.

Comment: thank u.but I'm newbie in node and what I should exactly add to my code?

Comment: After the data is received by your server (node), what do you want to do with it?

Comment: insert them in mongodb, with their index and values.

Comment: So if your form is using method GET, just use the `req.query` variable to insert into mongo: `db.collection('collection_name').insert(req.query, function(err,docs){})`

Comment: Yes, if you use the express body parser: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: No problem. If this has helped out, could you please accept or vote up the answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have to use `req.body` instead of `req.body.name`, and it will give me each index and its value.Like a json file.